# Domino Designer shows 'unknown property' on my custom tag in extension plugin

Tags: xpages

I am currently extracting my common xpage code from my databases and packaging it in an eclipse extension plugin.  Everything is working fine except for my extension of RichText tag.
The tag shows up in the Designer Palette and I can insert it onto the page, but none of the standard attributes (id, rendered, etc.) are recognized and I get an 'unknown property' error.  This means I cannot build the NSF.
This same code worked in the the database itself, but does not work when I use it in the plugin.
Does anyone have any idea why this WORKS in my database but DOES NOT WORK in my plugin?

The xsp-config is as follows (almost exactly the same as that in the openntf [XPages Rich Text Editor Evolution](http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?action=openDocument&name=XPages%20Rich%20Text%20Editor%20Evolution) project; just namespace-uri, default-prefix and component-class have been changed):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config>
    <faces-config-extension>
        <namespace-uri>http://aivisto.com/xsp/control
        </namespace-uri>
        <default-prefix>ap</default-prefix>
    </faces-config-extension>
    <component>
        <description>A control that displays a field for entering multiple
            lines of rich text.
        </description>
        <display-name>Rich Text</display-name>
        <component-type>com.ibm.xsp.InputRichText</component-type>
        <component-class>com.adpunctum.aivistox.extlib.ckeditor.component.InputRichText</component-class>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.core</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.core.prop.styleClass</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.core.prop.title</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.events.prop.onclick</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.events.onkey</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.focus</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.i18n</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.input.prop.disabled</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.input.prop.onchange</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.input.prop.readonly</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.outerStyleClass</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.filter</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.dojoUsage.deprecated</group-type-ref>
        <group-type-ref>com.ibm.xsp.group.aria.role</group-type-ref>
        <property>
            <description></description>
            <display-name>CSS Style</display-name>
            <property-name>style</property-name>
            <property-class>java.lang.String</property-class>
            <property-extension>
                <pass-through>true</pass-through>
                <designer-extension>
                    <category>styling</category>
                    <editor>com.ibm.workplace.designer.property.editors.StylesEditor</editor>
                    <styles-excluded>background, font</styles-excluded>
                </designer-extension>
            </property-extension>
        </property>
        <component-extension>
            <javadoc-description>
                <p>Rich Text Control</p>
                Control that provides Rich Text Editor functionality through CKEditor
            </javadoc-description>
            <base-component-type>com.ibm.xsp.UIInputRichText</base-component-type>
            <renderer-type>com.ibm.xsp.InputRichText</renderer-type>
            <tag-name>inputRichText</tag-name>
            <designer-extension>
                <category>Aivisto Extension</category>
            </designer-extension>
        </component-extension>
    </component>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Does the Domino Debug Plugin from OpenNTF offer any more information? http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects/pmt.nsf&documentId=A46D9A6788249D40862577D000541841&action=openDocument. It's recommended usage for developing your own plugins and debugging them when they don't work.

Comment: @Paul: Thanks for the comment.  Yes I have the Debug Plugin and it works great.  This is however a build time problem.  I can't build my nsf.  It seems that for some reason Designer does not recognize the tag inheritance (base-component-type).  This wasn't clear from my original post.